# Custom slider and autolayout issues

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UIView subclass with a xib that I'm trying to make in to a slider with discrete points on it.

I have a "track" and a "thumb". Along the track I want there to be 4 circles that are spaced evenly, that the thumb can snap to as it's dragged along.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    // Layout circles
    for index in stride(from: numberOfCircles, to: 0, by: -1) {
        let xValue = (((index - 1)/(numberOfCircles - 1))*track.frame.size.width) - circleSize/2 + thumbWidth.constant/2
        makeCircle(withXValue: xValue)
    }
}

fileprivate func makeCircle(withXValue xValue: CGFloat) {
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    circle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: xValue , y: self.frame.height/2 - circleSize/2, width: circleSize, height: circleSize)).cgPath
    circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 79/255, blue: 84/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(circle)
}
```

I think this would work, however, the `track.frame.size.width` is incorrect. This is because I'm adding this `UIView` subclass to another view and using autolayout to set its width. The width it returns in `awakeFromNib()` is just its value in the xib.
How can I get the actual autolayout width of the track to fix this problem?

Comment: If I put the code from `awakeFromNib()` in `layoutSubviews()` and then make sure it only gets called the second time `layoutSubviews()` is called, it works. But that seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Try `layoutSubviews()` - but be aware it may be called more than once. EDIT: Just saw your comment - yes, a bit tacky, but the best way. (If it were a view controller you'd have better options.)

Answer (score 0):

Make path independent on position

```
circle.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: circleSize, height: circleSize)).cgPath
```

Instead of this use `position` property of `CALayer` class:

```
circle.position = CGPoint(x: xValue , y: self.frame.height/2 - circleSize/2)
```

Save your circle layers in property so you can access them when frame gets changed. Let your layer's creation method return layer it created `makeCircle(withXValue xValue: CGFloat) -> CAShapeLayer`. And save it inside `awakeFromNib()`: `circles.append(makeCircle(withXValue: calculateXValueForCircle(atIndex: index))`

When frame of your view will change, method `layoutSublayers` will be called. Override method `layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer)` to set position using new frame value:

```
    override func layoutSublayers(of layer: CALayer) {
        super.layoutSublayers(of: layer)
        if layer == self.layer {
            for (index, circle) in circles.enumerated() {
                let newX = calculatePositionForCircle(atIndex: index)
                let newY = self.frame.height/2 - circleSize/2
                circle.position = CGPoint(x: newX, y: newY)
            }
        }
    }

    // Calculating X position better move in method so you don't dublicate your code
    fileprivate func calculatePositionForCircle(atIndex index: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return (((index - 1)/(numberOfCircles - 1))*track.frame.size.width) - circleSize/2 + thumbWidth.constant/2
    }
```